# Reverse Osmosis Tank Not Filling After Filter Change

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchen-sink

I just replaced my RO filters and now my tank is empty and not filling. I detached the supply line to the tank and NO water came out aside from an initial spray so I'm not sure what the issue is. The pressure in the tank is around 7psi. I'm not sure what the canister on the right is, I'm guessing it's for extra water storage.
First pic is before I did anything and the others are after I changed the filters. 
[image: This pic is before]
[image: This pic is after]
[image: This pic is after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of two things to check and the first I hate to even ask. 1) did you forget to open the valve at the top of the tank? 2) Check to make sure none of the tubing became crimped or pinched anywhere. Unless you removed more connections than needed, system flow should not have changed but here is diagram of system (you may have one more filter in line with the charcoal filter) http://www.waterfiltersonline.com/installation-diagram-4-5-stg.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response Larry. So I redid the filters and tried to find where the disconnect was. There actually is only a tiny amount of water initially coming out of the house that leads into the tank. Both pre filter canisters were filled with water so I think it is something after that. I took out the Polish filter and it seemed to allow water through but only drips at a time. The only thing I can think of is if it's the ASO valve but I'm not sure how to test it. Water does appear to be draining though, and it sounds like it's constantly draining.

Comment: Was the unit working B4 you changed filters? It sounds like the RO membrane is in backward or the rubber seal is deformed allowing water to bypass the membrane and go directly to waste in which case no water is actually passing through the membrane.

Comment: Yes it was working perfectly before and I didn't do anything with the membrane.

Comment: In both of your 'after' pictures it appears that the red handle on pre-filter is in the off position. The red handle has to be inline with the valve body to be open. Otherwise, if no tubing is crimped anywhere restricting flow then the ASO may be bad.
https://www.amazon.com/Automatic-Shut-Off-Quick-Connect-Fittings-Reverse/dp/B00BC057UK/ref=asc_df_B00BC057UK/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=193984242218&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=235978714453618259&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9005439&hvtargid=pla-311367557928&psc=1

Comment: In rethinking this, if the ASO were not opening then you would not hear water flowing to waste. It is also possible that the membrane is clogged so that only the brine / waste is passing water. Do you pre-rinse the charcoal filter to flush out any loose particles before you insert it in housing?

Comment: I did not prewash the carbon filters, but I can try that later. The red handle is off in the photos, but I left it on for 24 hours and the tank was still empty. I just had it off at that time to save water. I appreciate your help by the way, thank you!

Comment: Interestingly enough the drain hose does NOT go through the ASO. I just replaced the ASO and there is definitely some progress, but it doesn't seem to be 100%. after 24 hours of the water being on, the tank still isn't heavy, but there is some flow from the faucet, which wasn't happening before. So I'm not sure what's going on, but progress is good. I am close to ordering a new unit entirely.

Comment: Well looks like replacing the ASO valve worked and waiting 2 days. The tank is full now and I'm so relieved. Thank you Larry, your diagram was super helpful and you motivated me to keep looking at it!